# For Loop to Programmatically hide elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to programmatically hide div elements on a page using an Array and loop in jQuery, but it doesn't seem to work.

I have done alerts and console.log to confirm the array is firing and the loop is working through the items, but it's the .hide() method that seems to be giving issue.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       var divsToHide = ["fin_0", "fin_1", "fin_2", "fin_3", "fin_4", "fin_5", 
"fin_6", "fin_7", "fin_8", "fin_9", "fin_10", "fin_10-1", "fin_10-2", "fin_10-3", 
"fin_10-4", "fin_10-5", "fin_10-6", "fin_10-7", "fin_10-8", "fin_10-9", "fin_20", 
"fin_21", "fin_22", "fin_23"];

    $.each(divsToHide, function(index, value)
    {
        var currentDiv = "div#" + value;
        var stringCurrent = currentDiv.toString();
        var currentHide = $(' stringCurrent ');

            console.log(currentDiv);
            currentHide.hide();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Try with remove your div tag from the element ID and also remove the single quotes from currenthide variable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably use:

```
var currentHide = $(stringCurrent);
```

Your code

```
var currentHide = $(' stringCurrent ');
```

has no reference to `stringCurrent` variable, it just try to find `<stringCurrent>` element.

Answer (score 5):

Even better, you should use

```
 $.each(divsToHide, function(index, value)
 {
    $("#" + value).hide()
 });
```

since an element id should be unique to the document

Comment: Or just `'#' + value`, as the `div` part is irrelevant when selecting by `id`.

Comment: Modified my answer based on @Rory McCrossan's comment

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `'` around stringCurrent. Otherwise your string is not interpreted but jquery searches for `' stringCurrent '`